# How do I create a calculated measure that is simply a count of members from a dimension

Tags: mdx

How can I display the count of records (accounts) from a dimension in a calculated measure.
For example, the following expression is the MDX to list all Accounts.

```
     [Customer Credit].[Account Name].[Account Name].members
```

Is it possible to create a Measure, that will have the COUNT of all Accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the MDX [count](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Count.html) function:

```
with member [Measures].[My Count] as 
      [Customer Credit].[Account Name].[Account Name].members.count
select [Measures].[My Count] on 0
from [your-cube]
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this count filtered by the amount of measures referenced in a query?  If i select particular Account Names, i would like to have the [My Count) adjust to match.  If i need to create another question for this i will.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Guess better a new question with an example; do not understand it right now.